# Installing Windows service with parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I have a series of basically identical custom services, which needs to be started with different parameters. The parameters specify which ports to use to communicate with an application, and they all need different ports. I install the services with a batch script:

```
cd %~dp0\InterfaceService_0x1C01
installutil interface.exe

cd %~dp0\InterfaceService_0x1C02
installutil interface.exe
```

Then start them like so:

```
cd %~dp0\InterfaceService_0x1C01
net start Interface0x1C01 /-ip=127.0.0.1 /-pn=32790 /-sp=32791

cd %~dp0\InterfaceService_0x1C02
net start Interface0x1C02 /-ip=127.0.0.1 /-pn=32792 /-sp=32793
```

It works fine, they all start up on different ports. But when I restart the computer, they start automatically without parameters. I've tried to modify the install script:

```
cd %~dp0\InterfaceService_0x1C01
installutil Interface.exe
sc config Interface0x1C01 binPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\InterfaceServices\InterfaceService_0x1C01\Interface.exe /-ip=127.0.0.1 /-pn=32790 /-sp=32791"

cd %~dp0\InterfaceService_0x1C02
installutil Interface.exe
sc config Interface0x1C01 binPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\InterfaceServices\InterfaceService_0x1C02\Interface.exe /-ip=127.0.0.1 /-pn=32792 /-sp=32793"
```

I've also tried without the slashes, but in both cases the service starts up on the default port.

Can someone help with this? I'd like this approach to work, but I could also accept help with installing them set to not start automatically and having a script start them automatically on startup - provided that the user would not need admin privileges at that point.

Comment: I would advise that you use the Service Control tool, `sc.exe`, instead of `net.exe`. With that you could try to `create` the service, e.g. `@"%__AppDir__%sc.exe" Create Interface0x1C01 binpath= "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\InterfaceServices\InterfaceService_0x1C01\Interface.exe\" -ip=127.0.0.1 -pn=32792 -sp=32793" type= interact type= share start= auto obj= LocalSystem`. To configure it, replace `Create` with `Config`.

Comment: I used sc config to add the binpath in the modified install file, but i changed the install file to use sc, unfortunately I get the same result. The services start without the parameters. If I stop them and use the stratup script they still work.
Installation looks like this now:
`@"%__AppDir__%sc.exe" Create Interface0x1C01 binpath= """"%~dp0\InterfaceService_0x1C01\Interface.exe""" -ip=127.0.0.1 -pn=32790 -sp=32791" start=auto obj= LocalSystem`

`@"%__AppDir__%sc.exe" description Interface0x1C01 "Service to communicate with interface PCB with ID 0x1C01"`

Comment: As you've seemingly changed your path from a location in `Program Files` to one relative to the batch file, why did you change the quoting I have used? Using my syntax, it should have looked like this for that path: `binpath= "\"%~dp0InterfaceService_0x1C01\Interface.exe\" -ip=127.0.0.1 -pn=32792 -sp=32793"`, not: `binpath= """"%~dp0\InterfaceService_0x1C01\Interface.exe""" -ip=127.0.0.1 -pn=32790 -sp=32791"`. _(Please note that there should be a space between `start=` and `auto`, and `%~dp0` already carries a trailing backslash, which you'd not catered for either.)_

Comment: I changed the syntax because escaping the " with a backslash did not work for some reason - I just got the help message for sc instead of a result. But putting two quotes does the job, the install succeeds, and the options all work. The services start, but still all on the same port. I did remove the interact parameter since i got a message saying it's deprecated.
The folder is the same, I just cleaned it up so users can install the scripts more easily.